# XMLPATH has an invalid token

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to extract all the ndoes whose Date element has today's DateTime except seconds which is 10 seconds less than datetime.now.

Here is the code.

C#

```
   DateTime total_seconds = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-10));
        string st = "_127.0.0.1";
        //string v = "1";
        XPathNodeIterator itr = nav.Select("pings/ping" + st + "[DATE<" + total_seconds + "]/DATE");
```

XML

```
<pings>
  <ping_127.0.0.1>
    <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
    <RTT>0</RTT>
    <DATE>13-09-2015 16:47:09</DATE>
  </ping_127.0.0.1>
  <ping_127.0.0.1>
    <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
    <RTT>1</RTT>
    <DATE>13-09-2015 16:47:10</DATE>
  </ping_127.0.0.1>
  <ping_127.0.0.1>
    <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
    <RTT>2</RTT>
    <DATE>13-09-2015 16:47:11</DATE>
  </ping_127.0.0.1>
  <ping_127.0.0.1>
    <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
    <RTT>1</RTT>
    <DATE>13-09-2015 16:47:12</DATE>
  </ping_127.0.0.1>
</pings>
```

This is the error

Comment: You wrote _"This is the error"_, but forgot to paste in the error. What is the error (incl. top of stacktrace).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> XPathNodeIterator itr = nav.Select("pings/ping" + st + "[DATE<" + total_seconds + "]/DATE");
> ```

While you haven't pasted in the error, from the title it says: "Invalid token". Your code suggests a string as XPath statement something along those lines:

```
pings/ping_127.0.0.1[DATE<37712828]/DATE
```

But since the `total_seconds` variable is of type `DateTime`, I assume it is a string something like "2015-10-09...13:22:56.584". Which is most likely the cause of your invalid token.

If not, can you put a breakpoint in your code and paste the resulting XPath?

Note: what you are trying to achieve is not (quite) possible, you cannot compare a date/time value with greater-than operators in XPath 1.0. It requires at least XPath 2.0 to do that. A workaround is, unfortunately, not trivial.